# raspberry pi ,windows 10 iot core, code c# save file .txt

Tags: pi-3

I have C# code of a sensor that detects whenever an object is near or far. I am implementing this on a Raspberry Pi. The code should display a message saying 'close' or 'far'. What I want is to capture the number of times you move toward or away from an object and save this as a .txt file.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
// ...
using Microsoft.IoT.DeviceCore.Input;
using Microsoft.IoT.Devices.Input;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
using Windows.UI;
using System.Text;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

namespace AvoidanceSample
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var controller = GpioController.GetDefault();
            var SwitchSensor = new Switch()
            {
                Pin = controller.OpenPin(6)
            };
            SwitchSensor.Switched += SwitchSensor_Switched;
        }

        private async void SwitchSensor_Switched(ISwitch sender, bool args)
        {
            await Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync((s) =>
            {
                if (args)
                {
                    StatusText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    StatusText.Text = "close";

                }
                else
                {
                    StatusText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    StatusText.Text = "far";

                }
            });
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Some info on the sensor would be great, if its purely a code problem Stack Overflow is the place to be asking.

Comment: I'd suggest migrating to Stack. It's a trivial task (StorageFolder/StorageFile stuff), but with some caveats around async operations and file locks that might benefit from 'experts'. I'd take a crack, but I've gone and reformatted all my IoT Pi's.

Comment: You are not asking a question. What's the question?

Comment: You have a lot of code in here related to a UI, but IOT core has no UI...

Answer (score 1):

You never tried to save a file in your code... easier way is like that:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(storageFile, text);
```